# Switching camera from front to back in pjsip iPhone

Tags: iphone, sip, pjsip

I am working on pjsip video calling app. I want to switch preview camera in an ongoing call.

Here is the code that I am trying.

```
pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param param;
pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default(&param);
param.cap_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV;
pj_status_t status = pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(_current_call, 
PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_CHANGE_CAP_DEV, &param);
if (status == PJ_SUCCESS)
{
   NSLog(@"Toggle");
}
```

I am not able to switch camera using above code.

I have also added below code before adding account in pjsip

```
acc_cfg.vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE;
acc_cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE;
acc_cfg.vid_cap_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV;
acc_cfg.vid_rend_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_RENDER_DEV;

pjmedia_orient orient;
orient = PJMEDIA_ORIENT_ROTATE_90DEG;
pjsua_vid_dev_set_setting(PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV, 
PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_CAP_ORIENTATION, &orient, PJ_TRUE);
```

If there is any other method please guide me.

Comment: Hi @Nazrul Islam, I had a problem when I set camera pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(), function work fine, but in receiver device the video come too lag and it take a lot of time for show the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pjsua_call_set_vid_strm()` is the correct method already, just try to change the capture device ID (i.e: `param.cap_dev`). Note that `PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV` means the default capture device, which on iPhone normally is the front facing camera.

You can use `pjsua_vid_dev_count()` and `pjsua_vid_dev_get_info()` to enumerate available video devices. Capture devices should have direction info (`pjmedia_vid_dev_info.dir`) set to `PJMEDIA_DIR_CAPTURE`. And device name info (`pjmedia_vid_dev_info.name`) should tell which one is the back camera.

Comment: Hi @nanang, i had a problem when I set camera pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(), function work fine, but in receiver device the video come too lag and it take a lot of time for show the video.

Comment: Hi @nanang, when I call pjsua_call_set_vid_strm to stop and resume transmit video my app was block all thread. I can not do any thing.

Comment: Video Dir PJMEDIA_DIR_DECODING
Device Name OpenGL renderer
Device ID 0
Video Dir PJMEDIA_DIR_ENCODING
Device Name Colorbar generator
Device ID 1
Video Dir PJMEDIA_DIR_ENCODING
Device Name Colorbar-active
Device ID 2

I got three device none of it is PJMEDIA_DIR_CAPTURE